# How to troubleshoot CIFS error -13 (Permission Denied)?

Tags: windows, debian, mount, cifs

I am trying to mount a share (D$) from Debian (running inside Hyper-V) on my Windows 8 computer, using the following command:

```
sudo mount -v -t cifs //192.168.99.1/D$ /media/d -ocredentials=/home/emi.smbcredentials,sec=ntml
```

However, the command fails with the following output:

[image]

The share works fine from other computers, username/password/domain are correctly set and network connectivity is there. Additionally, I can see the following in the Windows Event Log:

[image]

In the kernel log on Debian, I can see the following errors:

```
Status code returned 0xc000006d NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

What would be the right approach to find the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only admins can access disk hidden shares.
Try to share again volume D on the windows box using sharename "diskd" or similar, add permissions for user emi to the share and retry to connect to the new share from linux.
Check for ntfs permissions too. Only share permission are not enough to read shared directories.

Comment: I'll try, thanks. "emi" is in group Administrators, however.

Answer (score 1):

See if it is an encryption issue, try Set-SmbServerConfiguration -EncryptData 0

(with this as 1 on my windows server I get identical errors on a synology trying to mount a windows CIFS share)